# Any common methods to integrate $\frac {\int dx P(x) x r(x)}{\int dx P(x) r(x)}$ when $P(x)$ is a guassian distribution?

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral, clustering

I am currently studying David MacKay's Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms.

In chapter 20, where he talks about modify kmean algorithm into a soft kmean algorithm (Gaussian Mixture Model).

In  the equation, P(x) is the gaussian distributioin, r(x) stands for the probability of a point belong to an arbitrary cluster.

The reduced form of $\frac {\int dx P(x) x r(x)}{\int dx P(x) r(x)}$ is $2\int dx P(x) x r(x)$

This implies the bottom will equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.

I know that $\int dx P(x) = 1$, but I don't understand how to get rid of $r(x)$.

Or there are other ways to integrate the equation?

Here is the original question and solution:

[image: Question]
[image: Question]

Comment: So you question is how to see that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty [\exp(-x^2/2)/\sqrt{2\pi}][1+\exp(-2\beta m x)]^{-1} dx = 1/2$?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a faster way to get the result or do we have to integrate it?

Comment: awesome, thanks for your helpful link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a = \beta m$. If we differentiate the integral with respect to $a$, we get
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2x P(x)e^{-2a x}}{(1+e^{-2ax})^2}dx= 2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x P(x)}{[e^{ax}(1+e^{-2ax})^2]}dx = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x e^{-x^2/2}}{(e^{ax}+e^{-ax})^2}dx = 0,
$$
where in the last step we used the fact that the integrand is clearly odd. Thus, the integral is constant with respect to $a$, and in particular is equal to its value when $a=0$. So
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{P(x)}{1+e^{-2\beta m x}}dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{P(x)}{1+e^{0}}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(x)dx = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Our good friends at WolframAlpha [confirm that this is the case](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5B-x%5E2%2F2%5D%2FSqrt%5B2Pi%5D%2F%281%2BExp%5B-a+x%5D%29%2C+%7Bx%2C-Infinity%2CInfinity%7D%2CAssumptions-%3Ea%3E0%5D).

As for the other integral, it is possible to show using integration by parts that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2xP(x)}{1+\exp(-2\beta m x)}dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P\left(\frac{u}{\beta m}\right)\,\mathrm{sech}^2(u) du,
$$
but neither of these integrals appear in any tables I can find.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But could you tell me why the integral is equal to its value when a=0?

Comment: @Kelvin_neverKnow The $a$-derivative of the integral is $0$, so the value of the integral doesn't depend on $a$ at all. That means we can evaluate it at any $a$ we choose and get the same answer. $a=0$ just happens to make for an easy evaluation.

Comment: @Kelvin_neverKnow I should add that differentiating an integral with respect to its parameter in the hopes of creating a simpler integral is a fairly common method of handling integrals.

Comment: that's really helpful, thank you.